# Why calculated fields using scalar functions are slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have below table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [InternalSiteId]  AS (isnull(CONVERT([int],[dbo].[GetCurrentTemporalValue]([Id],'Client_InternalSite')),(0))),
    [BudgetingStatusId]  AS (isnull(CONVERT([int],[dbo].[GetCurrentTemporalValue]([Id],'Client_BudgetingStatus')),(1))),
    [BusinessUnitId]  AS (isnull(CONVERT([int],[dbo].[GetCurrentTemporalValue]([Id],'Client_BusinessUnit')),(0))),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Client] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

which has 3 calculated fields using scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCurrentTemporalValue]
(
    @clientId INT,
    @temporalType NVARCHAR(128)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @retVal INT
    DECLARE @at DATETIME

    SET @at = GETUTCDATE()

    SELECT @retVal = CAST(Value AS INT) FROM dbo.Temporal 
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND ClientId = @clientId 
    AND TemporalType = @temporalType
    AND ( ValidFrom <= @at OR ValidFrom IS NULL ) 
    AND ( ValidTo >= @at OR ValidTo IS NULL)
    
    RETURN @retVal
END
GO
```

and this function uses below table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temporal](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [TemporalType] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Temporal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The Client table has around 2500 records but the `select * from [Client]` takes about 14 seconds!

When I comment these 3 calculated fields, it gets back to normal value below one second. So the scalar function seems to cause the issue.

I tried to make condition easier ( left only 1 = 1 ) but it didn't change the speed.

What I want to achieve is:

- historical values (kept in Temporal table)
- current value to be pointed out by Client.InternalSiteId, Client.BudgetingStatusId and Client.BusinessUnitId
- I cannot just simply make InternalSiteId a regular int fields with foreign key to, let say, InternalSiteHistoryTable as there are ValidFrom and ValidTo fields pointing out the period in which given value is valid and current and e.g. ValidFrom can be set to future value. That's why I need such calculations in function to find out current value.

What should I do / change to achieve above goals, but keep the reasonable fetching data speed?

Comment: User defined Scalar functions can be notoriously slow. I would recommend that you don't have these computed columns and use a `VIEW` instead.

Comment: Your function only takes 1.8 ms per call. Since you call it 7500 times (3 * 2500) it takes 14 sec. If you want it sub-second, you are better-off joining your `Temporal` table to `Client` instead of repeatedly calling your scalar function.

Comment: If you really need using function, then you at least need to create proper indexes for 'temporal' table, also try to get rid of various casts and converts. Creating a view is greatly preferred however.

Comment: Arguably you should use a proper System Versioned Temporal table, then you can use normal foreign keys. Because the way those work is that they use two separate tables: current and history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a view to join to your `Temporal` table instead of embedding function calls

```
-- Table without those functions to slow things down
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientName](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Client] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) 
ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

--instead, use a view to do the same thing
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Client] as 
   SELECT
       ClientName.Id,
       ClientName.Name,
       isnull(CONVERT([int], Client_InternalSite.Value), 0) AS InternalSiteId,
       isnull(CONVERT([int], Client_BudgetingStatus.Value, 1) AS BudgetingStatusId,
       isnull(CONVERT([int], Client_BusinessUnit.Value, 0) AS BusinessUnitId
   FROM ClientName INNER JOIN 
       ( SELECT Value, ClientId
         FROM Temporal
         WHERE TemporalType='Client_InternalSite'
          AND ( ValidFrom <= GETUTCDATE() OR ValidFrom IS NULL ) 
          AND ( ValidTo >= GETUTCDATE() OR ValidTo IS NULL)
       ) AS Client_InternalSite ON ClientName.ID = Client_InternalSite.ClientID
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT Value, ClientId
         FROM Temporal
         WHERE TemporalType='Client_BudgetingStatus'
          AND ( ValidFrom <= GETUTCDATE() OR ValidFrom IS NULL ) 
          AND ( ValidTo >= GETUTCDATE() OR ValidTo IS NULL)
       ) AS Client_BudgetingStatus ON ClientName.ID = Client_BudgetingStatus.ClientID
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT Value, ClientId
         FROM Temporal
         WHERE TemporalType='Client_BusinessUnit'
          AND ( ValidFrom <= GETUTCDATE() OR ValidFrom IS NULL ) 
          AND ( ValidTo >= GETUTCDATE() OR ValidTo IS NULL)
       ) AS Client_BusinessUnit ON ClientName.ID = Client_BusinessUnit.ClientID
```

GO

I can't test this against your DB, so I don't know about your indexes on your `Temporal` table (ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo columns), but typically a VIEW like this is going to run quicker because the tables are queried only once.